# Regex to check url with only one occurrence of character "?" and that too after specific image formats

Tags: c#, regex

I want to place a validation to check image url so that i get only one occurrence of "?" and that too after specific image formats.

```
https://img1.com/1.jpeg: valid

https://img2.com/16.png?bg=0: valid

https://img3.com/15.jpg?bg=0&wmi=n : valid

https://img4.com/1?2.jpg?bg=0&wmi=n : invalid (two ? in url)

https://img5.com/12.jpg??bg=0&wmi=n : invalid (two ? in url)

https://img6.com/1.xyz: invalid (jpg|png|gif|jpeg only supported)
```

Also, image formats can be jpg|png|gif|jpeg.

I have tried using

```
\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)(?=\?|$)
```

which works fine but cannot detect more than one occurence of "?"

Comment: how about this one `https:\/\/(www\.)?[\w.]+\/[\w]+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|gif)(\?)?[^\?]+$`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match with the valid urls than you can use expression below

```
(?i)/([^?]*?)\.(png|jpe?g|gif)\??(?!\?)
```

It matches all valid urls and doesn't match all invalid.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\.(?i)(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)(?:\?[^?]+)?$
```